# Vuetify inherit styles in component

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

I am working on component, which has many links. I would like to style each link using some built-in classes (like "font-weight-regular ma-3 text-center") and some custom styles.
I would like to have one common css class to apply to each link, so I don't need to apply 4 classes.

How can I do that?

I tried to use scss and `@extend`, but then I receive `The target selector was not found.` error.

Here is example style:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped="scoped">
  .text {
    @extend .font-weight-regular;
    @extend .ma-3;
    @extend .text-center;
    display: block;
  }
</style>
```